# Inspecting console.log() with cordova

Tags: android, cordova, console

I'm trying to find a way to look at my console.log() output for my phonegap (Cordova) app. I've had trouble with every method I've tried in any tutorial I came across. I could really use some help.

**Update**: I've using ubuntu 14.04, with a samsung s3 connected via usb with usb debugging enabled.

This is my logcat aias

```
adb logcat | grep `adb shell ps | grep com.myapp.app | cut -c10-15`
```

It give me way to much info, I just want my console.log's but that's not even the problem. I don't get my console.logs, I just get a whole lot of other weird stuff.

Any help would be great.

Comment: Please explain what part of this document is unclear: https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap/wiki/Debugging-in-PhoneGap

Comment: possible duplicate of [Filter LogCat to get only the messages from My Application in Android?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6854127/filter-logcat-to-get-only-the-messages-from-my-application-in-android)

Comment: This questions may have an answer here references exactly where I got the logcat command that isn't working the way I need it to : )

Answer (score 1):

You can watch this video on youtube. shows how to debug on samsung S3. Yo

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wv1x24CZrvY

also have a look to a similar query
[Using adb logcat with a real phone (and not the emulator)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3707880/using-adb-logcat-with-a-real-phone-and-not-the-emulator)

Hope it helps.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/9869609/1027004 That's what I was looking for : ) Thanks so much!!!!