# Android: Debug app-release.apk

Tags: android, debugging, release

I'm working in Android Studio 2.2 RC on OSX 10.11 , and after implementing In-App Billing, after having generated my app-release.apk and having installed it on my phone, I noticed that when the purchase is successful and Ads are removed from my App, something in a secondary Activity of mine, is causing a NullPointerException and Activity is not loading.

To figure out what is causing it, I need to somehow debug the app while the In-App Purchase is active (debug.apk won't let me complete iAP) so...

**How do I debug a release apk that is installed on my phone?**

Comment: Why do you need to debug the release apk? You can debug before generating apk. In-App purchase result can be set for testing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the following steps:

1. Enable debug in your device and connect usb to your device use
2. command `adb devices` to list connected devices
3. use command `adb -s "device id" logcat` and hit `enter`

It will show you a lot of log message but don't worry. Just test your phone and it will show you the error. Use **ctrl + z** to stop the log and you can check your error.

Please read this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3707880/5241603). It will help more. Hope this will help you.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, I have tried going to the platorm tools dir. and running this command ./adb -d "193xxxx" logcat but it shows me the "guide" to use adb, s I guess it's not working, if it helps I'm on OS X

Comment: pls, try again. I updated my answer. use adb -s "device id" in the third step.