# Signed APK generated, installed but not working - Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, apk

How to check what is wrong with my APK? I installed it on my device but when I want to run it i get 'app forced to close'. I haven't got any error in Android Studio when APK is generating. How to check it?

Cheers!

Comment: What if you debug the app on your device via USB?

Comment: Having the phone connected to the computer should show you the error in the Logcat
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3707880/using-adb-logcat-with-a-real-phone-and-not-the-emulator

Answer (score 0):

you can use crash reporter libraries in android,they get your crash reports and store them on servers.

here is a [link](https://github.com/JStumpp/awesome-android#crash-monitoring) to some awsome crash reporters