# View a Fragment inside a frameLayout in mainActivity

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

I am working on my first android application.
**

- **What I am trying to do:**

1- view this blank fragment inside a **frameLayout** in the main activity:
**fragment_map.xml** (fragment xml file )

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MapFragment">

    <!-- TODO: Update blank fragment layout -->
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:text="@string/hello_blank_fragment" />

</FrameLayout>
```

2- the FrameLayout is inside the mainActivity like this:

**activity_main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MainActivity">

<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/mapPlaceHolder"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"></FrameLayout>

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

3- Trying to add this fragment into the FrameLayout dynamically using the function **showMap()**

**MainActivity class**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    boolean activityIsReady= false;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    }
    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        activityIsReady = true;

    }
    @Override
    protected void onPostResume() {
        super.onPostResume();
        showMap();
    }

    void showMap(){
        if(activityIsReady == true) {
            FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction =  getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
            fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.mapPlaceHolder, new MapFragment());
            fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null);
        fragmentTransaction.commit();
        }
    }

}
```

4- **MapFragment** code (I just creted a new fragment and this java class was generated automatically)

```
public class MapFragment extends Fragment {
   // TODO: Rename parameter arguments, choose names that match
   // the fragment initialization parameters, e.g. ARG_ITEM_NUMBER
    private static final String ARG_PARAM1 = "param1";
    private static final String ARG_PARAM2 = "param2";

// TODO: Rename and change types of parameters
private String mParam1;
private String mParam2;

private OnFragmentInteractionListener mListener;

public MapFragment() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}

/**
 * Use this factory method to create a new instance of
 * this fragment using the provided parameters.
 *
 * @param param1 Parameter 1.
 * @param param2 Parameter 2.
 * @return A new instance of fragment MapFragment.
 */
// TODO: Rename and change types and number of parameters
public static MapFragment newInstance(String param1, String param2) {
    MapFragment fragment = new MapFragment();
    Bundle args = new Bundle();
    args.putString(ARG_PARAM1, param1);
    args.putString(ARG_PARAM2, param2);
    fragment.setArguments(args);
    return fragment;
}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    if (getArguments() != null) {
        mParam1 = getArguments().getString(ARG_PARAM1);
        mParam2 = getArguments().getString(ARG_PARAM2);
    }
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_map, container, false);
}

// TODO: Rename method, update argument and hook method into UI event
public void onButtonPressed(Uri uri) {
    if (mListener != null) {
        mListener.onFragmentInteraction(uri);
    }
}

@Override
public void onAttach(Context context) {
    super.onAttach(context);
    if (context instanceof OnFragmentInteractionListener) {
        mListener = (OnFragmentInteractionListener) context;
    } else {
        throw new RuntimeException(context.toString()
                + " must implement OnFragmentInteractionListener");
    }
}

@Override
public void onDetach() {
    super.onDetach();
    mListener = null;
}

/**
 * This interface must be implemented by activities that contain this
 * fragment to allow an interaction in this fragment to be communicated
 * to the activity and potentially other fragments contained in that
 * activity.
 * <p>
 * See the Android Training lesson <a href=
 * "http://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating.html"
 * >Communicating with Other Fragments</a> for more information.
 */
public interface OnFragmentInteractionListener {
    // TODO: Update argument type and name
    void onFragmentInteraction(Uri uri);
}
}
```

***The Problem is : the application crashes after it starts immediatly.***

I've tried to call showMap() in OnCreate() function.But, It had not been executed.

**LogCast**: I've found these lines in red but, I am not using  **AudioFlinger**

```
2018-12-10 13:23:25.747 1496-2985/? E/AudioFlinger: not enough memory for AudioTrack size=131296
2018-12-10 13:23:25.747 1496-2985/? E/AudioFlinger: createRecordTrack_l() initCheck failed -12; no control block?
2018-12-10 13:23:25.748 2732-6423/? E/AudioRecord: AudioFlinger could not create record track, status: -12
2018-12-10 13:23:25.756 2732-6423/? E/AudioRecord-JNI: Error creating AudioRecord instance: initialization check failed with status -12.
2018-12-10 13:23:25.756 2732-6423/? E/android.media.AudioRecord: Error code -20 when initializing native AudioRecord object.
```

Comment: Troubleshoot by seeing your logcat response.

Comment: post `MapFragment` code.

Comment: I updated the question with logcast.But, I could not find out a solution.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44702884/app-crashes-when-button-is-hit-although-no-errors-shown

Comment: I think that everything is fine in AndroidManifiest.xml file @Badr

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue occur due to interface. You have two option.

**(1)** implement `OnFragmentInteractionListener` in your `MainActivity`. Like,

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements OnFragmentInteractionListener {
   .......
   @Override
   void onFragmentInteraction(Uri uri){
       ....
   }
}
```

**(2)** If you no need to interface then remove listener code from `onAttach`.

```
@Override
public void onAttach(Context context) {
  super.onAttach(context);
  //remove code from here.
}
```

Comment: thanks, I had to read the comments in MapFragment class, I will read it and figure what i need!!.

Comment: So if i did not implement this interface I will not be able to interact with the fragment in the mainActivity !?

Comment: If you want to interact with mainactivity , you can implement interface with your custom method.