# How to read android bug report and logcat

Tags: android, logcat

If I saw some error message on my phone,

I want to check and learn why it pop it error.

I used comment like `adb bugreport` or `adb logcat`.

It will output some file or '.txt'.

Then how check on file or txt.
because it will pop out a lot of information.
how to find the error point.

I tried <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>F</kbd> error. it will find about 500 'error' word.

Comment: are you using android studio?

Comment: I am not sure because i flashing my devices . This version is someone build. I just want to know if one day i get QA testing(android) and i want to check logcat and bugreport . then easy to describe my issues! thanks a lot!

Comment: you need to have an android programming ide(like android studio) to trace your errors and debug your device via usb debugging

Comment: Yes I have Android studio,then how can use it. thanks for teaching !

Comment: Please have a look at this [logcat using terminal - SOF](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3707880/7948109) and this [logcat using terminal - Android Dev](https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/logcat)

Comment: how do you install your app on your device?

Comment: To debug your app on your physical device, you need to turn on your developer mode >> allow usb debugging then connect your phone to PC via usb

Comment: Maybe i describe wrong way,it not a application.

Comment: Maybe i describe wrong way,it not a application. ex. I download new version to flash my devices to other version . and after setting ,maybe Original application "chrome or Gmail " crush or keep stopping , and i used `$adb logcat`.

Comment: And I want learn "How to get the crush point."