# WinForms on Android

Tags: c#, android, winforms, cross-platform, mission-planner

There is a Mission Planner program on PC (which I think is written in Winforms), it also exists on Android, how was this program ported? after all, when I used it, I see the cursor and some floating windows similar to WindowsXP windows
[image]

[image]

I was looking for a solution, but everyone says to use xamarin or Maui

Comment: I would use [adb logcat with a real phone](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3707880/295004) to see what messages appear when starting the app. The log message may hint at what engine (Unity, Qt, Xamarin, Maui, other) the app may be running.